# remove keys in a dictionary if a value in its dictionary field is a subset

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I need to get the **cat_n** with maximum matches and remove **cat_m** if it is a subset.
For example

`vehicle_dict = {"cat_1":{"type":["car", "bus", "auto"]}, "cat_2": {"type":["car", "auto"]}}`

should return

`{"cat_1":{"type":["car", "bus", "auto"]}}`

but

`vehicle_dict = {"cat_1":{"type":["car", "bus", "auto"]}, "cat_2": {"type":["car", "train"]}}`

should return both i.e

`{"cat_1":{"type":["car", "bus", "auto"]}, "cat_2": {"type":["car", "train"]}}` as none of them are a subset.

So for

`vehicle_dict = {"cat_1":{"type":["car", "bus", "auto"]}, "cat_2": {"type":["car", "auto"]}, "cat_3": {"type":["car", "train"]}}`

it should return

`{"cat_1":{"type":["car", "bus", "auto"]}, "cat_2": {"type":["car", "train"]}}`

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Comment: What do you mean by "maximum matches"?

Comment: Are values in `'type'` going to be unique? If no, when both `['a', 'b']` and `['a', 'a', 'b']` are present, is one preferred over the other? When `'type'` values are identical, which one should stay (e.g. `['a', 'b']` and `['a', 'b']`)? Since they are lists and not sets, do you consider `['a', 'b']` and `['b', 'a']` to be identical?

Answer (score -1):

I assume that the goal is to filter the vehicle_dict as follows:
For each category cat_x in sequence, exclude the category if all its types have already been seen in previous categories.

The code:

```
def filter(vehicle_dict):
    result = {}
    all = set()  # Set of all types types encountered so far
    i = 0  # Categoey number in the result
    for cat in sorted(vehicle_dict.keys()):
        types = vehicle_dict[cat]['type']  # Get the category types
        typeset = set(types)  # Make a set out of the types,
        # If and only if the category contains new type(s) it is included in the result
        if not typeset.issubset(all):
            i += 1
            result[f'cat_{i}'] = vehicle_dict[cat]  # Include the category in the resul
t
            all = all.union(typeset)  # Keep track of all types encountered so far.
    return result

vehicle_dict = {"cat_1":{"type":["car", "bus", "auto"]}, "cat_2": {"type":["car", "auto"]}}
print(filter(vehicle_dict))

vehicle_dict = {"cat_1":{"type":["car", "bus", "auto"]}, "cat_2": {"type":["car", "auto"]}, "cat_3": {"type":["car", "train"]}}
print(filter(vehicle_dict))
```

Output

```
{'cat_1': {'type': ['car', 'bus', 'auto']}}
{'cat_1': {'type': ['car', 'bus', 'auto']}, 'cat_2': {'type': ['car', 'train']}}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but I think you should first explain code.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks.